# is Tina Sprout an initiator and a mechanical soldier?

Tags: black-bullet

In the subbed episodes of Black Bullet I'm watching, if rightly translated, they seem to say Tina Sprout is a mechanical soldier? is this so? Why an initiator who already has superhuman habilities (enhaced strenght, speed, recovery, etc.) would need mechanical parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tina Sprout is both a Cursed Child (Initiator) and a mechanical soldier.

> Initiator inquiry into Tina Sprout’s name. Her IP rank is 98. She’s an owl Initiator and one of the enhanced NEXT soldiers. I saw her specs, and her numbers are terrifying. Enju will be killed!”
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 2: Against a Perfect Sniper (p. 125). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

Why? It makes her the perfect sniper and assassin. Her mechanical implants allow her to make extraordinary shots that she would not be capable of even with her Initiator powers by providing her control over her body and mechanical systems like Shenfield (or automated guns for attacking) that can feed information directly to her brain

> This was Tina Sprout, and just like Rentaro, she had a sniper rifle loaded and ready, ignoring said “Big Brother” as she kept a watchful eye down her scope. The Bits that formed part of her aiming system flitted at regular intervals between her and the target Gastrea. Those were the infantry of sorts for her Shenfield, a thought-driven interface that, like so many buoys strewn across the sea, transmitted wind speeds and other pertinent sniper information directly into her brain.
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 5 (light novel): Rentaro Satomi, Fugitive (Kindle Locations 257-260). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

.

> “The man in the video used an advanced version of that. With a neurochip implanted in his brain, he can control a number of devices with just his thoughts. Those Bits are like scouts. They have precise observation instruments installed, and they send information about the location of the target, including its coordinates, temperature, humidity, angle, and wind speed, wirelessly to the brain of the operator. That’s why that man could shoot through the targets blindfolded. Of course, the surgery the sniper underwent was not just for this. “I have heard that shaking hands are also a great enemy to snipers. It is likely that a metal balancer was implanted in the body to completely shut down any movement to the hand from heartbeats or breathing. Putting something like that in is a piece of cake for someone like me or Ain. Rentaro, do you understand what this means?”
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 2: Against a Perfect Sniper (pp. 145-146). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

As for the reason for the NEXT project, it can be gleaned from this passage.

> “Rentaro, let’s do a simple calculation that even you can understand. Let’s assume that my New Humanity Creation Project and Ain’s NEXT have the same amount of hidden power. If we subtract the abilities of a mechanized soldier from you and that assassin, what do we have left? The unsurpassable wall between a human and an Initiator. Can a human beat a gorilla? Think about it carefully. Rentaro, just stay on the sidelines this time. There’s no need for you to take any more risks than you already have.”
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 2: Against a Perfect Sniper (p. 147). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

The strength of a Cursed Child far exceed that of a regular human and the ability of an enhanced (mechanized) Cursed Child is superior to anything else